# Use of || in NodeJs

Tags: c++, node.js

I'm new to NodeJs so please be gentle but I'm stuck here so a little help would be appreciated.
I was going through the documentation of NodeJs and I didn't know what this statement does.

```
 if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber())
```

Here is the [code](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_function_arguments) and line 14.
In C or other languages it would mean "OR" but that doesn't seems to be the case here.

Comment: it is the case, || is logic OR. why do you think of the contrary?

Comment: If you are new to node.js, why are you reading the section of the manual about writing addons? Ignore that part for now.

Comment: That code (and that part of documentation) is about C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still an or-operator. It's checking that the first and the second argument (stored in `args`) are numbers.

And the language you're looking at is C++, not JavaScript (Node.js). C++ is the language in which Node.js is implemented and you can also use it to write low-level addons.

Comment: what range? that expression in javascript assigns to symbols (the first from the left) a default value `SYMBOL_DEFAULT` if `symbols` (the second from the left) evaluates to false.

Comment: @SaurabhRana: That's not the question you asked. Ask another question. Or better yet, search StackOverflow for that syntax since it is a question that has been asked here a hundred times and any new question asking it will be closed as duplicate with a link to a similar previous question.

Comment: sorry I'm answering to deleted comments there :|

Comment: Sorry @DRC that was my mistake and you answered my question. So thanks - thanks a lot.

Comment: @DRC: Good point, of course it should say C++. I keep neglecting the difference :) Edited.

Comment: Thanks to you too @Jakob. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @Jakob for example one of them doesn't have classes :)